# How do we choose the dimension of $h_0$ and weights in GRU?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

[image]

As an example, a simple GRU is shown in the above picture. The update equations are:

\begin{aligned}z_{t}&=\sigma _{g}(W_{z}x_{t}+U_{z}h_{t-1}+b_{z})\\r_{t}&=\sigma _{g}(W_{r}x_{t}+U_{r}h_{t-1}+b_{r})\\{\hat {h}}_{t}&=\phi _{h}(W_{h}x_{t}+U_{h}(r_{t}\odot h_{t-1})+b_{h})\\h_{t}&=(1-z_{t})\odot h_{t-1}+z_{t}\odot {\hat {h}}_{t}\end{aligned}

- Question 1: How do you go about choosing the dimension of $h_0$?
- Question 2: Is the product of $W_z x_t$ a vector (n-dimension) or a
  scalar (1-dimension). Because we are taking the logistic function of
  this product, so I am wondering if this operation is performed
  element-wise in the case $W_z x_t$ is a vector.  Also, does this mean that the $1-z_t$ is a vector subtraction, e.g., $1$ is the vector of ones.
- Question 3: How do you choose the dimension of $W_z, U_z$ (and $W_r,
     U_r$, etc.) when you initialize them?

Answer (score 3):

Q1: It's a hyper-parameter, so there is no single answer. Values to try depend on your problem, and previous works on the literature. If none, you'll be guessing, or guiding your network to an embedding dimension.

Q2: $W_zx_t$ is a vector of the same size as $h_t$, the embedding dimension. So, the sigmoid operation is element-wise and $1-z_t$ is also a vector subtraction, where $1$ is the vector of ones of the same size as $h_t$.

Q3: After choosing the hidden state (embedding) dimension, all the matrix dimensions are already determined because you already know the dimension of $x_t$. For example, $W_zx_t$ is a matrix multiplication, and the number of columns of $W_z$ should be equal to the dimension of $x_t$. Also, the number of rows of $W_z$ should be equal to the dimension of $z_t$, and thus $h_t$, the embedding dimension. Similar logic applies to all matrices.

Comment: So, the number of columns and rows of **_U_** should both be equal to the dimension of  **_h_**? E.g. if the input dimension is 10 and the hidden state dimension is chosen to be 1, W will be 1 row by 10 cols and U will be 1x1? Or, if the input dim. is 10 and the hidden state dim. chosen to be 3, W will be 3 rows by 10 cols and U will be 3x3?

Comment: The dimensions you mention seem correct.